# Wordpress Read More still displaying in blog post in single.php page

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress ReadMore still displaying in blog post in single.php page

```html
<?php
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

   get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

   the_post_navigation();

   // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
   if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
    comments_template();
   endif;

  endwhile; // End of the loop.
  ?>
```

screenshot[image]

Comment: Hi @Charmos Melon, please share your code of **content-single.php** file placed in **template-parts** folder of your theme

Answer (score -1):

Are you using code like `the_content( 'Continue reading ' );` or `the_excerpt` in the template part file you've including there? Can you include code of that file?

Comment: hello. if you want to ask something about the question or code please add it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks guys for the response. I figured it out already. I replace the get_post_type() to a 'page' instead. 

The default parameter get_post_type maybe is pointing to the content.php post type in excerpt format right?

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar Thanks for informing. I'm aware of that. But, it says You must have 50 reputation to comment. Do you have any idea about commenting even if I've less than 50 reputation? Also, I think I'm not asking only question, I was providing hint there. I'm here just to help.